# Read multiple .Wav file from my computer and merge them as numpy arrays

Tags: python, numpy, wav

Helow. I am new to **python**, i have around 200 numpy array files which are .wav file and i want to merge them...i am using this code but it take very much time to achieve what i want.

```
from scipy.io.wavfile import read, write import numpy as np

fs, x = read('test1.wav') f2, y = read('test2.wav')

z = x + y                     this is to "mix" the 2 sounds, probably not what you want z = np.concatenate((x, y))     this will add the sounds one after another

write('out.wav', fs, z)
```

please need help on this

Answer (score 0):

Use pyaudio library to merge the .wav file. If you need any help refer this link, already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45700970/pyaudio-how-mix-wave-file-into-a-continuous-stream).